# Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, logstash, kafka-consumer-api

Im trying to setup my cluster with elk and kafka inside docker containers, but always logstash cant consume data from the kafka. Producer based on my local machine, not inside docker. I appriciate any help.

docker-compose:

```
  zoo1:
image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper
restart: always
container_name: zoo1
ports:
  - "2181:2181"
environment:
  - ZOO_MY_ID=1
  - ZOO_SERVERS=2181
  - ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181
  - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes


 kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka
    hostname: kafka
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zoo1
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zoo1:2181
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT_HOST://0.0.0.0:9092, PLAINTEXT://kafka:9093
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9093,PLAINTEXT_HOST://kafka:9092
  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
      - kafka
```

logstash.conf:

```
input {
    kafka {
        topics => ["topic-ex"]
        bootstrap_servers => "localhost:9092"
    }
}
```

Trace:

```
logstash_1       | [2021-03-28T04:39:54,855][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][540d5db3f43043788c8c88c0e41536de536f338e7ba9b86852861fc54f459599] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Connection to node -1 (localhost/127.0.0.1:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
logstash_1       | [2021-03-28T04:39:54,856][WARN ][org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient][main][540d5db3f43043788c8c88c0e41536de536f338e7ba9b86852861fc54f459599] [Consumer clientId=logstash-0, groupId=logstash] Bootstrap broker localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected
```

Edit: added logstash container and stack trace

Comment: Where is your logstash running? In a container? Why didn't you add it in your compose file? Also, you need to uncomment the listeners variable so that port 9092 and 9093 will work

Comment: @OneCricketeer Thank for your time! Im changed the question.

Comment: You understand localhost refers to the current container, right?

Comment: You mean in compose configuration? Im changed it now. But in logstash configuration localhost refers to my machine, isn't it?

Comment: No, localhost always refers to the current computer, for the your logstah container localhost refers to the same container, it is a [loopback address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost). You need to point your configuration to the hostname of the kafka container.

Comment: Were u able to fix it ? I am also getting the same error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Im just change bootstrap_servers in logstash.conf from "localhost:9092" to "kafka:9092".
I thought logstash and kafka must connect oustide of container. Thanks for help, everyone.

Answer (score 0):

With compose yaml you can not define locahost as hostname anymore. First add network bridge to both of your services then kafka will be your hostname. `kafka:9093`

Comment: What do you mean "anymore"? And compose creates a default bridge that can be used

Comment: Can you pls elaborate ?